# How to assign a zero to genric Number in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, zero

I'm new to Kotlin, and I'm trying to write a simple generic method but it doesn't compile

```
inline fun <T:Number> List<T>.firstOrZero() : T {
    if (isEmpty())
        return 0   // this line doesn't compile
    else
        return this[0]
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't really handle this case in a fully generic way in Kotlin. Whatever solution we choose, we have to handle each type of `Number` separately.

Therefore, I suggest to not go with a generic function, but with multiple overloads:

```kotlin
fun List<Int>.firstOrZero() = if (isEmpty()) 0 else this[0]
fun List<Long>.firstOrZero() = if (isEmpty()) 0 else this[0]
```

This should be potentially faster than generic solutions using reflection, because the type is resolved at the compile time instead of runtime.

If you have more cases like this, your cases are more complicated, etc. and you are concerned about the code duplication, you can inline the common code:

```kotlin
fun List<Int>.firstOrZero() = firstOrDefault { 0 }
fun List<Long>.firstOrZero() = firstOrDefault { 0 }

private inline fun <T:Number> List<T>.firstOrDefault(default: () -> T) : T {
    if (isEmpty())
        return default()
    else
        return this[0]
}
```

But for the specific case of `firstOrZero()` I think it is an overkill.

Comment: I'm surprised it works for the `Long` case without saying `0L`.  Because you can actually specify the return type as `Number` like this `fun List<Long>.firstOrZero() : Number = if (isEmpty()) 0 else this[0]` and then it's no longer a `Long`

Comment: @Ivo Kotlin magic ;-) But I get your point. If I think about it, I'm not sure how Kotlin decides on the type of `0` in the case provided by you. The case in the answer is rather clear to me, it picks `Long`. In your case... I'm not sure if it's `Long` or maybe `Int`.

Comment: I've tried it as `fun List<Long>.firstOrZero() : Number = if (isEmpty()) 0 else this[0]` and then `println(listOf<Long>().firstOrZero() is Int)` prints true

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I guess if Kotlin can infer the exact type of `Number`, then it uses it when we provide literals. If it can't infer the type, as in `val foo = 5` or in your example, it picks a default type of `Int`.

Comment: Of course it's an overkill. I just asked with simplest example I could think. I wanted to implement was a more complex calculation which needed a zero.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to handle it for every single `Number` subclass you want to support. For example like this

```
inline fun <reified T : Number> List<T>.firstOrZero(): T {
    return (if (isEmpty()) when (T::class) {
        Int::class -> 0
        Double::class -> 0.0
        Float::class -> 0f
        BigInteger::class -> BigInteger.ZERO
        else -> throw RuntimeException()
    }
    else
        this[0]) as T
}
```

Comment: Are there any benefits of using a generic function instead of multiple overloads? Multiple functions should be match faster as they are resolved at the compile time. And we can't avoid handling each case separately anyway.

Comment: @broot I actually don't know. Now you mention it I can imagine multiple overloads being better. It also prevents getting an exception by going into the `else` in this generic solution. I'm guessing "less lines of codes" is maybe the only benefit

Answer (score -3):

You need to ensure that the return type matches the expected type.

Because you defined the generic type 'T', you need to return 'T', which extends 'Number'.

```
inline fun <T : Number> List<T>.firstOrZero(): T {
    if (isEmpty())
        return 0 as T
    else
        return this[0]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. `as T` is an unchecked cast. It would throw an exception if you do certain things with the return value later on.

Comment: For example: `val x = listOf<BigInteger>().firstOrZero()` throws an exception.

Comment: @Sweeper, this doesn't throw an exception for me. It's actually a neat solution

Comment: @ModdyFire How could it not throw? It casts an `Int` to `BigInteger`: https://pl.kotl.in/xvHaE0yOi . Could you provide a full example in Kotlin Playground which doesn't throw for you? @Sweeper is correct, this solution is not type-safe, it may throw `ClassCastException` in some cases.

Comment: I agree that it is not safe, but it works for every built-in Kotlin Number I tried

https://pl.kotl.in/hIBlfrN8G

Comment: @ModdyFire That works only because `println()` doesn't care about the type of the passed value, it won't notice if we pass `Int` as `BigInteger`. Now do pretty much anything with this value, pass it to any place where `BigInteger` is expected or even create a local variable and you will get CCE: `val x = list.firstOrZero()`.

Comment: You are absolutely right

Answer (score -4):

There is a way to do it. You can use the default keyword to provide a default value for the `T` type parameter. In this case, the default value will be 0. The following code will compile and run:

```
inline fun <T:Number> List<T>.firstOrZero() : T {
    if (isEmpty())
        return 0.default<T>()   // this line compiles
    else
        return this[0]
}
```

The default keyword can be used to provide a default value for any type parameter. This can be useful when you want to make sure that a method or property always has a value, even if the type parameter is not specified.

In this case, the default keyword is used to provide a default value of 0 for the `T` type parameter. This means that if the `T` type parameter is not specified, the method will return 0.

Here is an example of how to use the `firstOrZero()` method:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val firstNumber = list.firstOrZero()
println(firstNumber) // prints 1

val emptyList = emptyList<Int>()
val firstNumberInEmptyList = emptyList.firstOrZero()
println(firstNumberInEmptyList) // prints 0
```

Comment: What is this `default` function that you speak of? Got any documentation for that? I also have a slight feeling that this is AI generated...

Comment: `// this line compiles` ← this comment lies

Comment: (If _only_ I could simply add that comment to get any of _my_ code to compile…!)